# if statement [ -f $file ] not working

Tags: bash

I have the following:

```
while [ "${*}" != "" ] ; do

DPX_FOLDER="${1}"
TARGET_FOLDER="/Users/medialab/Desktop/07_DPX_checksums"/$(basename "${DPX_FOLDER}")
mkdir "${TARGET_FOLDER}"
echo
for file in "${DPX_FOLDER}"/*DPX/* ; do
    if [ -f "${TARGET_FOLDER}"/"$file" ] ; then
        echo "$file" exists, skipping
    else rsync -aPhi "$file" "${TARGET_FOLDER}"
    fi
    break 1
done
```

My script is not echoing `"$file" exists, skipping` even when the file does exist. It goes to the else statement and runs that every time. Is something wrong with my statement?

Comment: Are there spaces in your filenames? Also, your example is currently not reproducible.

Comment: @merlin2011, the quoting is correct (except for the quoting of the `$(basename "$DPX_FOLDER")` invocation), so spaces aren't a problem. On the other hand, the script expects the `DPX_FOLDER` directory to exist under `TARGET_FOLDER`, and *that* assumption is probably wrong.

Comment: You just created the target folder, so it should be empty. Why would the file already exist?

Comment: @chepner, indeed, though it's in an assignment, so it doesn't strictly have to be.

Comment: @Barmar because I run the script on a many directories at once, some of which have already had the script run on them, some which haven't.

Comment: Try putting `set -x` at the top of the script, so you see all the commands as they execute, with all the variables expanded. Then you should see the problem.

Comment: @Blake, if you want to indicate to readers that a directory may or may not exist, pass the `-p` argument to mkdir; that'll also stop it from logging an error when it *does* already exist.

Comment: BTW, if you'd made it `echo "${TARGET_FOLDER}/$file already exists, skipping" >&2`, you probably wouldn't have ended up here asking a question. :)

Comment: `"${TARGET_FOLDER}"/"$file"` is more simply written as `"${TARGET_FOLDER}/$file"`

Comment: ...so, bottom-line, this isn't really a bash question/bug, but a program-logic issue. I could argue for close-as-needing-MCVE, inasmuch as the code given doesn't constitute a standalone reproducer (creating, on its own, *all* the conditions for others to create/observe the bug; see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: (BTW, what's the point of the `break`? If you only want to rsync the first file to match the glob, why have a `for` loop at all?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought a for loop would be the best way to do it. What would be a better option?

Comment: If you don't mind overwriting your argv array, one very terse (and POSIX-compliant) option is `set -- "${DPX_FOLDER}"/*DPX/*; rsync -aPhi "$1" ...`

Comment: ...if you *do* mind overwriting your argv array, you can use a named array, making your code bash-only: `files=( "${DPX_FOLDER}"/*DPX/* ); rsync -aPhi "$files" ...` -- when referred to as just `"$arrayname"`, vs `"${arrayname[@]}"`, an array expands to its first element only.

Comment: Cool! Thanks, I will look into that. @CharlesDuffy

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly a case where `DPX_FOLDER` contains path elements you don't want in your destination.

```
DPX_FOLDER=/Users/hello/world
for file in "${DPX_FOLDER}"/*DPX/* ; do
```

...means that you'll have `file` values that look like `/Users/hello/world/123DPX/foo`

Thus, `"${TARGET_FOLDER}"/"$file"` will look like:

```
/Users/medialab/Desktop/07_DPX_checksums/world/Users/hello/world/123DPX/foo
#\---- "${TARGET_FOLDER}" -------------------/ |--- file -----------------|
#                                              |--- "${DPX_FOLDER}"----| *
```

Assuming that you don't have one `/Users` under your other `/Users`, then, appending the one path to the other is simply wrong.

Consider instead:

```
for file in "${DPX_FOLDER}"/*DPX/* ; do
    if [ -f "${TARGET_FOLDER}/${file##*/}" ] ; then
        echo "$file exists, skipping"
    else
        rsync -aPhi "$file" "${TARGET_FOLDER}"
    fi
done
```